# A word to describe an industry where personal growth depends on insider knowledge

Tags: adjectives, business-language

I am trying to come up with a word that describes an industry where your growth as a professional depends on learning from others, not from books or research.

Example: It's difficult for young people to establish a career in the space industry. Most jobs are gained through personal networks, and industry standards are typically passed via word-of-mouth through generations of workers - not easily accessible on the internet.

The sentence I'd like to write: Finding a mentor helps students establish themselves in a __ industry.

Words that are similar: Old boy's club, cliquey, exclusive

Comment: It might help to know if you're looking for a negative word that implies corruption (like nepotistic) or a neutral/factual word that just refers to needing to be mentored and get personal support and recommendations without any connotations of wrong-doing. Your examples (cliquey, old boy's club) sound negative, but the description sounds neutral.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a word for it, as it seems to apply to most highly technical industries.